# Illustrative pictures for the tags Info page

Tags: discussion, tags

I find that the tags Info page is somehow hard to read.

Would it be useful to have a simple pictures to illustrate the tag like the Wikipedia pages, for example putting the figure on the right hand side of [Special relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity) to our corresponding [tag](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/special-relativity/info)?

Also, it would be easier to visualize the relation between tags rather than just list all of them out, such as [Classical mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/classical-mechanics/info). Is there way to generate those graphs so that we can put them there?

Comment: I would be interested in seeing a [contingency table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table) for the most commonly-seen-together tags.  I'm not sure the SE platform actually supports a better tag page like you suggest.

Comment: @BrandonEnright But I think it is at least possible to put some pictures. I do know whether it is possible to make some partitions like <div> though

Comment: Should almost certainly be on the mother meta as this depends on and/or affects code that applies to the whole network.

Comment: @dmckee No one has suggested that before? I think it is a useful feature for the long tag wiki

Comment: I don't think thumbnailing would be possible without a really big change in the SE software. But +1, interesting idea.

Comment: @hwlau Not that I know of, but I don't read every post on MSO.